# Insufficient allowance on liquidate unit test

Tags: erc-20, foundry

I don't understand why I'm getting this error:

> When running this test I get an insufficient allowance error on the transferFrom function.

Here is my test:

```
    function testIfInsolventCanBeLiquidated() public depositedCollateralAndMintedDsc(USER) {
        //become undercollateralized (reduce collateral value)
        (bool success,) =
            ethUsdPriceFeed.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("updateAnswer(int256)", UNDERCOLLATERALIZED_ETH_PRICE));
        console.log("success state: ", success);
        assert(success);

        //create second user
        ERC20Mock(weth).mint(LIQUIDATE_CALLER, STARTING_ERC20_BALANCE * 200);

        console.log("dsc ", dsce.getDscValue(LIQUIDATE_CALLER));
        console.log("collateral", dsce.getAccountCollateralValue(LIQUIDATE_CALLER));

        vm.startPrank(LIQUIDATE_CALLER);
        ERC20Mock(weth).approve(address(dsce), AMOUNT_COLLATERAL * 2); //let engine get collateral
        dsce.depositCollateral(weth, AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);
        dsce.mintDsc(1e8);

        console.log("dsc liq", dsce.getDscValue(LIQUIDATE_CALLER));
        console.log("dsc user", dsce.getDscValue(USER));

        console.log("collateral", dsce.getAccountCollateralValue(LIQUIDATE_CALLER));

        //Liquidate
        dsce.liquidate(weth, USER, 100);

        vm.stopPrank();

        //check if became liquidated
    }
```

Here is the error:

```bash
    ├─ [22749] DSCEngine::liquidate(ERC20Mock: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], user: [0x6CA6d1e2D5347Bfab1d91e883F1915560e09129D], 100) 
    │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 2, 2000, 1, 1, 2
    │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 1, 100000000000, 1, 1, 1
    │   ├─ [993] MockV3Aggregator::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← 2, 2000, 1, 1, 2
    │   ├─ emit CollateralRedeemed(redeemedFrom: user: [0x6CA6d1e2D5347Bfab1d91e883F1915560e09129D], redeemedTo: liquidator user: [0xFBb867B41D72C5A4a8a0bEE31c1FE13788e2F0ac], token: ERC20Mock: [0xA8452Ec99ce0C64f20701dB7dD3abDb607c00496], amount: 5500000 [5.5e6])
    │   ├─ [3105] ERC20Mock::transfer(liquidator user: [0xFBb867B41D72C5A4a8a0bEE31c1FE13788e2F0ac], 5500000 [5.5e6]) 
    │   │   ├─ emit Transfer(from: DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512], to: liquidator user: [0xFBb867B41D72C5A4a8a0bEE31c1FE13788e2F0ac], value: 5500000 [5.5e6])
    │   │   └─ ← true
    │   ├─ [3016] DecentralizedStableCoin::transferFrom(liquidator user: [0xFBb867B41D72C5A4a8a0bEE31c1FE13788e2F0ac], DSCEngine: [0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512], 100) 
    │   │   └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"
    │   └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"
    └─ ← "ERC20: insufficient allowance"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line approves the engine to spend weth:
`ERC20Mock(weth).approve(address(dsce), AMOUNT_COLLATERAL * 2); //let engine get collateral`

I needed to also approve the engine to spend some DSC like so:
`dsc.approve(address(dsce), 100);`

> In short, I needed to approve the 2 tokens, not just the weth contract.

Answer (score 1):

add the following console.log statement:

```
console.log("AMOUNT_COLLATERAL ", AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);

ERC20Mock(weth).approve(address(dsce), AMOUNT_COLLATERAL * 2); 
dsce.depositCollateral(weth, AMOUNT_COLLATERAL);
```

what are you getting?